# Getting "window is not defined" in ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am trying to get the current url of the page, and store it as a value in a hidden input field with the name `redirect`:

```
<input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="" />
```

It is an EJS file. So if I try this, it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByName("redirect")[0].value = window.location.href;
</script>
```

But if I change it to the following, it doesn't work giving an error that `window is not defined`.

```
<input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= window.location.href %>" />
```

I am very new to javascript. Can someone please help me fix the second approach?

Comment: I thought that EJS was a templating language.  I wouldn't expect a language that constructs a document to be able to access document since document doesn't exist until it's done rendering.

Comment: `window` is global. It should be (and is) available **everywhere**, so this doesn't make a great deal of sense. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem.

Comment: @DominicTobias: sorry I didn't get your point

Comment: Where is that EJS template executing? in Node or the browser?

Comment: Is EJS really good solution for some DOM operations? In my opinion, getting document/window, while you are constructing it is a bad practice. Is there any reason for doing so?

Comment: @DominicTobias: in the browser

Comment: I have updated the question now.

Comment: Agree with LeoOdishvili although your problem doesn't make sense you should be passing the value as data when rendering the template and applying the value to the element `value="<%= url %>" />`. Also what EJS library and version are you using? @HenilShah

Comment: Hello you don't have access window.location because your render is from server, so in server you don't have this location, you need to use something a baseUrl config.

Answer (score 2):

Hello you don't have access to `window.location` because your render is on a server, and the server doesn't have this location, you need to use something like a `baseUrl` config.